# Update a combo box automatically when first combo box gets some value

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have two combo boxes. I insert one value in first combo box and now i want that my second combo box updates its value according  to first one. How should i do that?

Comment: Which technology are you using? WPF, Silverlight, winforms?

Answer (score 9):

Handle the [`SelectedIndexChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event for the first `ComboBox`, then update the second combo box based on the [`SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx) value for the first `ComboBox`.

A quick example (sans error handling when retrieving the SelectedItem):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string[] comboBox1Range = new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
    private string[] comboBox2RangeA = new[] { "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4" };
    private string[] comboBox2RangeB = new[] { "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4" };
    private string[] comboBox2RangeC = new[] { "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4" };
    private string[] comboBox2RangeD = new[] { "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4" };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
        comboBox1.Items.AddRange(comboBox1Range);
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedValue = comboBox1.SelectedItem as string;

        switch (selectedValue)
        {
            case "A":
                comboBox2.Items.Clear();
                comboBox2.Items.AddRange(comboBox2RangeA);
                break;
            case "B":
                comboBox2.Items.Clear();
                comboBox2.Items.AddRange(comboBox2RangeB);
                break;
            case "C":
                comboBox2.Items.Clear();
                comboBox2.Items.AddRange(comboBox2RangeC);
                break;
            case "D":
                comboBox2.Items.Clear();
                comboBox2.Items.AddRange(comboBox2RangeD);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Subscribe to first combobox's value changed event and populate the second:

```
combobox1.SelectedIndexChanged+= new EventHandler(ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);

private combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do stuff with combobox2
}
```

or

```
combobox1.SelectedValueChanged += new EventHandler(ListBox1_SelectedValueChanged);

private combobox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do stuff with combobox2
}
```

Population:

```
combobox2.Items.Add(new object());
combobox2.Items.Add(new ListItem("caption", "value"));
// etc
```

Find an existing item:

```
var index = combobox2.FindStringExact(combobox1.SelectedText);
if (index != -1)
    comobox2.SelectedItem = combobox2.Items[index];
```

Comment: what is syntax to populate the second?

Comment: I need to do that when first combo box gets a value 'a' for instance then second combo box should automatically show the last value in the drop down of combo box. I am not able to get the syntax to update the value of second combo box

Comment: There are already items in my second combo box, i just want the last item should be shown in  it when my firs one gets a certain value. i do not need to add anything in second combo box.

Answer (score 0):

Code Example, Winform with two comboBoxes databound to two tables in a dataset.
Table "lstCountries" list of current countries 
Table "lstState" list of all states/provinces for all countries.

Table lstCountries(Int32 CountryID,string CountryName)
Table lstStates(Int32 StateID, Int32 CountryID, string StateName)

In this code, I populate cboState based in value selected cboCountry 
while both combodropdowns are bound to data tables fetched from a database.

```
//  Load data from database (not shown)
// _dataSet.Tables["lstCountries"] datasource for cboCountry
// _dataSet.Tables["lstStates"] datasource for cboState
//  
// cboCountry - comboDropDown - List on countries 
// cboState  = comboDropDown  - List of states

// Use boolean bloading to prevent setting datasource for cboState when cboCountry is intially loaded.

    void cboCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cbo = (sender as ComboBox);
        if (cbo.SelectedIndex > -1 && !bloading)
        {
            Int32 countryID = Convert.ToInt32(((System.Data.DataRowView)(cbo.SelectedItem)).Row.ItemArray[0].ToString());

            cboState.Text = "";
            DataView view = _dataSet.Tables["lstStates"].DefaultView;
            view.RowFilter = string.Format("CountryID={0}", countryID);
            DataTable table = view.ToTable();
            cboState.DataSource = table;
            cboState.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to select Ders this cmbDers and then cmbKonu update related SQL like that Country-City. But I get a datatype mismatch. What is problem?

Form Load 
    OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Ders ", baglanti);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    baglanti.Open();
    adp.Fill(dt);
    cmbDers.DataSource = dt;
    cmbDers.DisplayMember = "DersAd";
    cmbDers.ValueMember = "DersID";
    baglanti.Close();

```
private void cmbDers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter ("select * from Konu where DersID = '" +cmbDers.SelectedItem+"'",baglanti);   
    adp.Fill(dt);
    cmbKonu.DataSource = dt;
    cmbKonu.DisplayMember = "KonuAd";
    cmbKonu.ValueMem`enter code here`ber = "KonuID";
    baglanti.Close();`enter code here`
```