# how to link comboboxes in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

I have two combo-boxes (A & B)  with same number of total options.
Every option in A is mapped to one option in B (one-to-one mapping).

Now what i want is as per selection of item in A, item in B should also change to its corresponding item in A which is selected. But reverse should not be true. changing selected item in B should not affect A's selection

Is there any feature in vb.net which allows such type of linking of combo-boxes?

Comment: Previously asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528842/update-a-combo-box-automatically-when-first-combo-box-gets-some-value

Comment: May be since it is c# i missed it. Thanks for pointing. But i got better one line solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
  private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     comboBox2.SelectedItem = comboBox1.SelectedItem;
  }
```

EDIT for VB.NET:

```
   Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
      ComboBox2.SelectedItem = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
   End Sub
```

Comment: Oh sorry, did you need that in VB.NET?

Comment: I tried above but its not working. Is combobox.selectedindex to be used in place of combobox.selecteditem?

Comment: You don't want to use combobox.selected index to match them up unless the two combo boxes will have the EXACT SAME items in the EXACT SAME order.  Did you set the method above as the event handler for ComboBox1's SelectedIndexChanged event?  Try putting a breakpoint in this code to see what the values are when you get there.