# How to manipulate comboBox with changing items?

Tags: c#, winforms

**Possible Duplicate:** [Update a combo box automatically when first combo box gets some value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528842/update-a-combo-box-automatically-when-first-combo-box-gets-some-value)

I have four comboBoxes in my form.

- comboBox1 has four values e.g 1.Bangla 2.Hindi 3.English 4.urdhu.
- comboBox2 has values which is depending on comboBox1:

  - If I select Bangla from comboBox1 then comboBox2 shows its values e.g 1-Maya 2-Mon mojaya.
  - If I select Hindi from comboBox1 then comboBox2 shows its values e.g 1-Monni 2-Chamali.
  - If I select Maya from comboBox2 then comboBox3 shows its values e.g 1-Habib 2-Ashif.
  - If I select Monni from comboBox2 then comboBox3 shows its values e.g 1-Sunidhi 2-Anu.

and so on.

How to manage them dynamically with click event?

Comment: Check out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528842/update-a-combo-box-automatically-when-first-combo-box-gets-some-value and answer of fletcher

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update a combo box automatically when first combo box gets some value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528842/update-a-combo-box-automatically-when-first-combo-box-gets-some-value)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SelectedIndexChanged event, and pass which index was selected to your function to populate the second box and so on.