# How to filter a combobox using another combobox in C#?

Tags: c#, combobox, filter

What I want to do is to filter a combobox with another combobox, I mean, there's going to be a combobox with the following items: "Animals", "Letters", "Numbers" and "Colors".

There's going to be another combobox that if you choose animals (for example) will display the following items: "Farm animals", "Home animals".

Then another combobox will filter the content, I mean, if she chooses "Farm animals" that combobox will only display animals like: "Pig", "Cow", etc. If she chooses "Home animals" it will display only animals like: "Cat", "Dog", etc. And a picture of the choosen animal.

Is this somehow posible?

Comment: Which technology are you using? It can differ greatly between ASP.NET and Winform/WPF. A good starting point would be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528842/update-a-combo-box-automatically-when-first-combo-box-gets-some-value), add to that the handling of postbacks if you're in ASP.NET

Comment: Hello, I'm using Windows Forms. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an event listener using the `ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged Event` so that when the index of the first combo box changes, the second combo box's values are determined.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)